# Excel Macro Move Row to Bottom

Tags: excel, vba

I've never used an excel macro before and was just given the task of writing a macro that moves a completed task to the bottom of the document 10 days after the entered completion date (i.e. if it was finished on April 14 and that was the date entered into the completion column then the whole row is moved to the bottom of the document).

Below is the table I made up to practice with.

```
Current_Date  Id  Samp1 Samp2 Samp3 Samp4 Samp5 Samp6 Completed_Date Completed_Plus_10  Real_C+10  Post
5/2/2016       1    a1    ab1   b1   bc1    c1    1     2/18/2016        2/28/2016      2/28/2016    Y 
5/2/2016       2    a2    ab2   b2   bc2    c2    2     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016       3    a3    ab3   b3   bc3    c3    3     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016       4    a4    ab4   b4   bc4    c4    4     4/21/2016        5/1/2016       5/1/2016     Y
5/2/2016       5    a5    ab5   b5   bc5    c5    5     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016       6    a6    ab6   b6   bc6    c6    6     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016       7    a7    ab7   b7   bc7    c7    7     3/14/2016        3/24/2016      3/24/2016    Y
5/2/2016       8    a8    ab8   b8   bc8    c8    8     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016       9    a9    ab9   b9   bc9    c9    9     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      10   a10   ab10  b10  bc10   c10   10     5/2/2016         5/12/2016      5/12/2016    N
5/2/2016      11   a11   ab11  b11  bc11   c11   11     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      12   a12   ab12  b12  bc12   c12   12     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      13   a13   ab13  b13  bc13   c13   13     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      14   a14   ab14  b14  bc14   c14   14     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      15   a15   ab15  b15  bc15   c15   15     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      16   a16   ab16  b16  bc16   c16   16     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      17   a17   ab17  b17  bc17   c17   17     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      18   a18   ab18  b18  bc18   c18   18     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      19   a19   ab19  b19  bc19   c19   19     1/10/1900           N
5/2/2016      20   a20   ab20  b20  bc20   c20   20     1/10/1900           N
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have seen the how to ask site. But I am _extremely_ new to macros and have absolutely no clue where to start or how it works. I have tried looking up instructions on other sites and I am still lost. This is for work--if I were just trying to figure it out for myself (without a deadline) I would spend more time practicing via trial and error until I got it right or got extremely stuck. But since this is for work I need do not have the time to do so.

Comment: I have attempted to create my own macro, but I don't know how to copy what I have tried into this site.

Comment: Copy it the same way you copied the table.

Comment: I used the "record macro" and have since lost the closest code I had trying to figure it out.

Comment: So record it again??? Edit: well, recording this won't help you. You need to program it from logic.

Comment: I'd suggest that you start here: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ After this short introduction into VBA you should have all the necessary knowledge to write the code yourself. And if you are running into errors / bugs while coding you can come back and we might be able to identify the error / bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little macro so that you don't have to start on an empty page:
My table looks as follows:

```
Date        id  samp1   samp2   Complete date
05.02.2016  2   abc     abc     asd
10.02.2016  4   ghi     ghi     01.02.2016
07.02.2016  3   def     def     asd
11.05.2016  5   jkl     jkl     06.05.2016
```

I used the macro recorder and copied the second line to the end of the table. Then I used "Find & Select" > "Go to Special" > choose "Blanks" > "Enter". Then I deleted them (found here: http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/delete-blank-rows-in-excel/).
In the recorded Macro I added the variable LastRow (to make it dynamically)

```
Sub mv()
'
' mv Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+Umschalt+A
'
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'here you sould add a loop over the rows and an the if statement
    Range("A3:E3").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'and here the end of the if statement and the loop        

    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CommandBars("Selection and Visibility").Visible = False
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.delete

End Sub
```

What the macro basically does:

- copy the Range("A3:E3")
- past it to the end of the table
- deletes empty rows

You can take this macro and adjust it to your Problem. Loop over the Rows and if the date (from column1) minus the date (from column5) is bigger than 10, then copy, else do nothing.

I hope this helps